# Answers with no references which have been contested for a long while

Tags: discussion, answers, references

I am well versed in the way that Psychology.SE and Health.SE work but I am new to Biology.SE so I am trying to find my feet a little here.

I came across a question here, [Why aren't we ambidextrous?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/14808/why-arent-we-ambidextrous), where [@AndroidPenguin](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/1757/androidpenguin) provided an accepted answer, which to @AliceD and I seems highly speculative ([See @AliceD's comment](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/14808/why-arent-we-ambidextrous/14866#comment51660_14866)).

To me, this is not a valid answer when there is doubt in its validity, and linking this question to [Should we [always] ask for references?](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294/should-we-always-ask-for-references), what do we do with such questions when references provide scientific evidence to back claims, and the person in question has been in hiatus since February 2015?

Comment: My opinion: leave a comment and down vote.