# You can only post once every 40 minutes?

Tags: discussion, support

When trying to post the question with the topic, [Answers with no references which have been contested for a long while](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3828), I got a message flagged up saying
[image]
This was because 27 minutes prior to that, I asked about  [Ligaments at the posterior superior iliac spine](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/74122) on Biology.SE (**non-meta**).

Because of the 40 minute block on questioning, I had to wait a further 40 minutes after asking the previous question on meta to ask this question also on meta.  This is frustrating when you may be researching a few things and have a few separate questions.

Does this apply between non-meta questions as well as meta to meta questions?

Why would asking a question on non-meta stop you asking a question on meta within 40 minutes of each other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any user with less than 125 rep need to wait 40 minutes before posting a question anywhere in the SE network. It was [implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277485/implement-cross-site-posting-rate-limits-to-slow-down-spammers) to slow down spammers from asking questions networkwide.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) for more information.